# VirtualBox and Security From Windows to Linux

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, virus

If I have VirtualBox, hosted by Windows 7 and I install Linux Ubuntu on this, is there any security risk if I use the Linux OS for the internet but the hosted OS (Windows) has no Virus protection software and I am in Admin mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring quite significant exploited vulnerabilities in Ubuntu, VirtualBox, *and* Windows, no.  However, you should be sure not to give the VirtualBox VM write access to many files, or it could conceivably use that to cause problems.  For example, just give it access to a single downloads folder which Windows can also see, and be very careful what you run from there.

Answer (score 0):

No.  At least not from Ubuntu.  Windows will (more or less) treat VirtualBox as a just another system process, and Ubuntu runs inside of that.  If your Ubuntu installation gets compromised, destroyed etc., it will have no affect on the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say there is no risk of infection getting from your ubuntu VM onto the host PC however there is a chance of you getting caught by something that port scans your PC from the internet and directly attacks it.  There are a number of vulnerabilities in windows that  do not require user interaction that will still be open to attack.